# Modify CSS variables / custom properties in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-variables

In my application, I've got some parameters that I wanted to put in CSS variables using jQuery. And I wanted to read them too.

I was having trouble to read the values back of the CSS variables and tried many things… before I found a solution in the “Questions that may already have your answer” while I was typing my question.

Anyway, I attached a snippet, because I need to know:
⋅⋅⋅ Why the method 1 isn't working ?
⋅⋅⋅ Is there a way to get the CSS var value using jQuery ?

I feel like it lacks an easy solution to handle CSS vars… Am I wrong ?
Of course I'll use the javascript solution if there isn't any way. But I'd like to be sure about it.
Thanks in advance for any answer.

```js
// This method doesn't work for writing CSS var.
$(":root").css("--color1", "red");
console.log(".css method on “:root”      :", $(":root").css("--color1"));

// This methods works for writing CSS var:
$(":root")[0].style.setProperty("--color2", "lime");
console.log("[0].style method on “:root” :", $(":root")[0].style.getPropertyValue('--color2'));
```

```css
#p1 {
  background-color: var(--color1);
}

#p2 {
  background-color: var(--color2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body id="bodyID">
  <p id="p1">p with background --color1</p>
  <p id="p2">p with background --color2</p>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: `setProperty` must create the property if she doesn't exist. Which seems to be the case

Comment: good to see you are considering them from you last question, unfortunately i cam late :) you already have the answer ;)

Comment: Anyway, @TemaniAfif, it's your "fault" if I came with another question ( kiddin' :) ). I thank you again for your answer to my other question, introducing me with CSS variables, it's really worth it.

Comment: welcome ;) i did this with everyone :) i throw new features and then questions start raining which is good for everyone as these ressources will be helful for future comers ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery only supports CSS custom properties in [version 3.2.0 and later](https://blog.jquery.com/2017/03/16/jquery-3-2-0-is-out). There is no support for them in 2.x or earlier, so accessing them with `.css()` will not work in those versions. If upgrading jQuery is not an option, you will need to use the built-in `style` object to access them.

```js
$(":root").css("--color1", "red");
console.log(".css method on “:root”      :", $(":root").css("--color1"));

$(":root")[0].style.setProperty("--color2", "lime");
console.log("[0].style method on “:root” :", $(":root")[0].style.getPropertyValue('--color2'));
```

```css
#p1 {
  background-color: var(--color1);
}

#p2 {
  background-color: var(--color2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">p with background --color1</p>
<p id="p2">p with background --color2</p>
```

Comment: Thanks you BoltClock, that was my problem. I verified the version of jQuery in my application, and it was 3.1.1…

Comment: @TemaniAfif : If the snippet was up-to-date, my code would have worked and I may have noticed what was the problem by myself ! So, yea, could be nice to update it. :)

Answer (score 2):

As [BoltClock mentions in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048660/5894241), jQuery added support for CSS variables starting from version 3.2.0.

But if you can't upgrade to the higher version for some reason, you could still [extend jQuery's `$.fn.css` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5007327/5894241) to work with the custom properties.

So here's my attempt at implementing a simple extension that checks if the property being modified is a Custom property or not ([by checking that it begins with two hyphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)). If it does, the custom property is modified using plain JS, else it calls the original implementation of `$.fn.css`.

```
(function() {
  var originalFnCss = $.fn.css;
  $.fn.css = function(prop, val) {

    // Check if the property being set is a CSS Variable.
    if (prop.indexOf("--") === 0) {
      if(val) {

        // Set the value if it is provided.
        for(var idx = 0; idx < this.length; idx++) {
          this[idx].style.setProperty(prop, val);
        }
      } else {

        // Get the computed value of the property.
        return window.getComputedStyle(this[0]).getPropertyValue(prop);
      }
    } else {
      return originalFnCss.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}());
```

**Note**: At the moment I have tested this extension with jQuery [1.11.1](https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/XZQYpq?editors=0110), [2.2.4](https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/oEOyoR?editors=0110) and [3.1.1](https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/aqxKEP?editors=0110), but do let me know if you find any bugs, or if you have any suggestions.

---

Now you just need to add the extension just after importing jQuery, or at any point before `$.fn.css` is invoked. Here's the working snippet:

```js
(function() {
  var originalFnCss = $.fn.css;
  $.fn.css = function(prop, val) {

    // Check if the property being set is a CSS Variable.
    if (prop.indexOf("--") === 0) {
      if(val) {

        // Set the value if it is provided.
        for(var idx = 0; idx < this.length; idx++) {
          this[idx].style.setProperty(prop, val);
        }
      } else {

        // Get the computed value of the property.
        return window.getComputedStyle(this[0]).getPropertyValue(prop);
      }
    } else {
      return originalFnCss.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}()); 

// This method doesn't work for writing CSS var.
$(":root").css("--color1", "red");
console.log(".css method on “:root”      :", $(":root").css("--color1"));

// This methods works for writing CSS var:
$(":root")[0].style.setProperty("--color2", "lime");
console.log("[0].style method on “:root” :", $(":root")[0].style.getPropertyValue('--color2'));
```

```css
#p1 {
  background-color: var(--color1);
}

#p2 {
  background-color: var(--color2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body id="bodyID">
  <p id="p1">p with background --color1</p>
  <p id="p2">p with background --color2</p>
</body>

<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version with a live [demo](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/ExVGxvb?editors=1111) -

// array with colors

```
var colConfig = [
  "default-bg",
  "hoverbg",
  "activebg",
  "maintxt",
  "subtxt",
  "listtxt"
];

let col_1 = ["#ffffff", "#f5f5f5", "#0065ff",'rgba(20, 20, 200, 1)', 'rgba(20, 20, 20, 1)', 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5)'];
let col_2 = ["#000000", "#5f5f5f", "#6500ff", "#1f1f1f", "#f1f1f1", "#000088"];

$("#default").click(function () {
  changeTh(col_1);
});

$("#new").click(function () {
  changeTh(col_2);
});

function changeTh(col) {
  for (let tag in colConfig) { 
    $(":root").css("--" + colConfig[tag], col[tag]);
  }
}
```