# Jquery how to change the background color of the header using toggle?

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to develop a darkmode feature for my website using jQuery's toggle method. At this point when the toggle is clicked the body colour changes, however, I wish for the header background colour to also change. How can I accomplish this?

current code base

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#checkbox').click(function(){
                var element = document.body;         
                element.classList.toggle("dark"); 
            });
        });        
    </script>
```

As seen you can use `document.body` to change the content of the body. I wish to achieve the same affect but for the header(and subsequently other elements)

P.S Jquery is mandatory

Comment: have you tried using CSS variables? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990354/how-can-i-modify-a-css-variable-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

This is done using jquery:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkbox').click(function() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dark");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  transition: background 0.2s linear;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #292c35;
}

.checkbox {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.label {
  width: 50px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #111;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.ball {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
}


/*  target the elemenent after the label*/

.checkbox:checked+.label .ball {
  transform: translateX(24px);
}

.fa-moon {
  color: pink;
}

.fa-sun {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox" class="label">
    <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    <i class='fas fa-sun'></i>
    <div class='ball'>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Just define both of your CSS and Switch class according to need.